# NodeJS and iso-8859-8 encoding

Tags: node.js, stream, icu

I am not sure what I am missing here...
I am streaming 8859-8 nodejs stream into utf nodejs stream, so piping it via decoder

```
sourceStream.pipe(oneStream).pipe(new TextDecoder('iso-8859-8')).pipe(anotherStream)
//or this
oneStream.setEncoding('iso-8859-8')
sourceStream.pipe(oneStream).pipe(anotherStream)
```

and getting "**ERR_ENCODING_NOT_SUPPORTED: The 'iso-8859-8' encoding is not supported**"
while I clearly see that inside *node/lib/internal/encoding.js* in Node12 sources there is such encoding:

```
 ['csiso88598e', 'iso-8859-8'],
 ['csisolatinhebrew', 'iso-8859-8'],
 ['hebrew', 'iso-8859-8'],
 ['iso-8859-8', 'iso-8859-8'],
 ['iso-8859-8-e', 'iso-8859-8'],
 ['iso-ir-138', 'iso-8859-8'],
 ['iso8859-8', 'iso-8859-8'],
 ['iso88598', 'iso-8859-8'],
 ['iso_8859-8', 'iso-8859-8'],
 ['iso_8859-8:1988', 'iso-8859-8'],
 ['visual', 'iso-8859-8'],
```

So, what am I missing?